# Position of JFrame on multiple screens

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, multiscreen

I want to determine the position of a `JFrame` on its screen. When i use `getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocation()` i just get *`w1` + `p`* but i want to determine just *`p`*.

```
______________   __________
|            |   | p  ____|     
|            |   |<-> |__||
|____________|   |________|
<---  w1  --->   <-- w2 -->
```

Using `getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDisplayMode().getWidth()` returns `w2` whats fine, but i'm not able to determine the `JFrames` position on the active screen.

My overall target is to ensure that the `JFrame` never has an area out of the visible screen area. E.g. if the `JFrame` is moved 100px up out of the visible area of screen #2 its corrected with moving it down for 100px.

How can i get the position of a `JFrame` on its active screen or make sure in any other way that the complete `JFrame` is visible (asuming `JFrame.size <= Screen.size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself and document it [on my website](https://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=62). In short, this code works for me:

```
public void moveToVisible(JFrame frame) {
    // Vertical position
    GraphicsDevice activeScreen = getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
    if (frame.getLocation().y < 0) {
        frame.setLocation(getLocation().x, 0);
    }
    if ((frame.getLocation().y + frame.getHeight()) > 
            activeScreen.getDisplayMode().getHeight()) {
        frame.setLocation(
                frame.getLocation().x,
                (activeScreen.getDisplayMode().getHeight() 
                 - frame.getHeight())
        );
    }
    // Horizontal position
    int offsetRight = frame.getX() + frame.getWidth() - frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds().x + frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds().width;
    if (offsetRight > 0) {
        setLocation(frame.getX() - offsetRight, frame.getY());
    }
    int offsetLeft = frame.getX() - frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds().x;
    if (offsetLeft < 0) {
        frame.setLocation(frame.getX() - offsetLeft, frame.getY());
    }
}
```

If someone knows a more easier solution let me know :)

Comment: there is problem with the certificate of your website. Else assume "DisplayMode" regards the screen scaling.